# Mopub banner ads failed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ads, mopub

I need to integrate the banner and interstitial ads to my apps. 
I implement the interstitial ads successfully. But I implement the banner ads I got some error message.

> 2018-04-19 16:27:43.581650+0800 22 Pushups[1591:276307] MOPUB: Banner view (<0ac59b0996d947309c33f59d6676399f>) loading ad with MoPub server URL: https://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=8&udid=ifa:XXXX&id=%3C0ac59b0996d947309c33f59d6676399f%3E&nv=4.20.1&o=p&sc=2.0&z=+0800&mr=1&ct=2&av=1.7.1&cn=CMHK&dn=iPhone8%2C4&w=640&h=1136&bundle=com.familyfit.itunes.22pushups&ats=1&vv=3
>   2018-04-19 16:27:43.879040+0800 22 Pushups[1591:276307] MOPUB: Banner ad view is fetching ad network type: clear
>   2018-04-19 16:27:43.879253+0800 22 Pushups[1591:276307] MOPUB: Ad unit <0ac59b0996d947309c33f59d6676399f> is currently warming up. Please try again in a few minutes.
>   2018-04-19 16:27:43.879565+0800 22 Pushups[1591:276307] MOPUB: Banner view (<0ac59b0996d947309c33f59d6676399f>) failed. Error: Error Domain=com.mopub.iossdk Code=1 "(null)"

I search many reference but cannot resolve. Please help! Thanks

Comment: Did you try with test unit ad id ?

Comment: yes. `0ac59b0996d947309c33f59d6676399f` this ad unit id is refer to sample app

Comment: Please show me the code you inplement, i think i can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)loadBanner {
    self.adView = [[MPAdView alloc] initWithAdUnitId:@"<0ac59b0996d947309c33f59d6676399f>"
                                            size:MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE];
    self.adView.delegate = self;
    self.adView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.width) / 2,
                               self.view.bounds.size.height - MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.height,
                               MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.width, MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.height);
    [self.view addSubview:self.adView];
    [self.adView loadAd];
}
```